# Mouse coordinates on Canvas without Jquery

Tags: javascript, canvas, mouse, jquery

I am currently using:

```
e.pageX - $("#canvas").offset().left
```

This is the only thing I am using Jquery for, so I would prefer to re-write this using just javascript.

What can I use to replace this?

Comment: I'd take a look at the jQuery source code, what they use inside the offset function.

Comment: I think it's `element.offsetLeft` and `element.offsetTop`. They probably use all sorts of other stuff though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer provided by N Rohler works well only in Internet Explorer (with some bugs prior to IE8 - but I guess it won't be a problem for you since you're using a canvas and pageX), and in Opera if the padding is 0, and in Safari/Chrome if the border width is 0 too. In Firefox, unfortunately, offsetX and offsetY are undefined.
http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html#mousepos

Kaninepete, I think you should reconsider, for the sake of simplicity, the way of getting the mouse coordinates relatively to your canvas element. All you have to do is to calculate the position of the canvas, which is a pretty simple task using .getBoundingClientRect() (also, don't forget to add scroll offsets if necessary), and subtract it from pageX and pageY.

Comment: I've switched it to:

    e.pageX - $("canvas").getBoundingClientRect().left

Is that what you meant?
It doesn't work in firefox.

Comment: Yes, your update should solve everything indeed, at least when the target has no top and left borders or paddings, just a bit redundant when `offsetX` or `offsetY` *is* actually 0 - I guess we can live with that.
(Just put a comma at the end of the line defining x, or put a `var` in front of y.)
(Sorry if I don't comment your answer, my reputation is still too low - halp!)

Answer (score 1):

```
var x = e.offsetX,
    y = e.offsetY;
```

Updated (again) for (correct) Firefox compatibility:

```
var rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
var x = e.offsetX || e.pageX - rect.left - window.scrollX,
    y = e.offsetY || e.pageY - rect.top - window.scrollY;
```

Comment: +1, don't know why this doesn't have more upvotes.  If you scroll down on a canvas and don't take into account the window.scrol[XY], your co-ordinates will be _wrong_.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace it by the below code

```
<canvas onmouseDown="mouseDown(event)" width="500" height="500"></canvas>


function mouseDown(e)
{
  var x=e.clientX-canvas.offsetLeft;
  var y=e.clientY-canvas.offsetTop; 
}
```